# Looping in ajax and controller (laravel) to post to endpoint multiple times with different IDs and Tokens

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm using laravel with form data, an ajax call and then a controller that will post a message to multiple endpoints and I'm not sure how to go about the looping structure.

I'm calling an endpoint that accepts the page ID, the token and the message but I have multiple page IDs and Tokens, so when the user types the message and hits submit I need it to post to all pages like so:

```
$post = $pagePost->post($id . '/feed/', $data, $accesstoken);
```

So hypothetically for each page we would be doing this for 4 pages:

```
post(1 . '/feed/', $data, 1234)
post(2 . '/feed/', $data, 12345)
post(3 . '/feed/', $data, 12346)
post(4 . '/feed/', $data, 12347)
```

By the time the blade with the form loads, I have all page IDs and access tokens loaded so when the user submits I need to make a call in a loop for each one and I'm just not sure how to go about This

Blade:

```
<div class="uk-grid uk-container-center ">
    @foreach($response['data'] as $page)
        <h2>{{$page['id']}}</h2>
        <h4>{{$page['access_token']}}</h4>
    @endforeach
</div>

$("#postNow").click(function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();

var post = $("#Post").val();
    $.ajax({

       type:'POST',
       url:'save',
       data:{post:post},
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
       success:function(data){  
            window.location.href = "/library";
       }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function Save(Request $request)
{
    $Post = $request->post;
    $data = array('post' => $post);

    //not sure where I need to do a foreach here
    $post = $pagePost->post($id . '/feed/', $data, $accesstoken);
}
```

Comment: Add another loop `@foreach($response['data'] as $page)` in the js part?

Comment: @Bryan you mean loop it in the ajax call?

Comment: Right, loop around that and generate the url with the loop data. When the page renders it will just be 4 `$.ajax` calls in a row.

Comment: I think that's definitely what I'm looking for, having multiple calls in a row. I'm not sure how to format that in the JS though? I can't use the laravel @foreach there can I?

Comment: Yeah, why not? The php part is rendered by the server, you can use it anywhere you want.

Comment: Ok cool, I'll give that a shot. I guess the loop should be around just the ajax call, so I'll see if I can get it going. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I'll add an answer as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reuse your loop in the javascript part:

```
var promises = [];
var promise;

@foreach($response['data'] as $page)
    promise = $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'{{$page['id']}}' + '/feed/' + '{{$page['access_token']}}',
       data:{post:post},
        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    });
    promises.push(promise);
@endforeach
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'save',
       data:{post:post},
       _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
       success:function(data){  
          window.location.href = "/library";
       }
  });
});
```

Notice I also tracked the promises. You don't want to leave a redirect in the success callbacks or the page could reload before they've all fired or finished.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense. Is there a way to, once these all finish, before loading the window location to hit the other ajax call and url with my controller procedure? IN other words, it would do all of these page url hits, then hit my 'save' url in controller and then reload the window?

Comment: Yeah. Inside the $.when function. Just replace the `window.location.href` with your original code.

Comment: Sweet, that makes sense I just wasn't sure if that was the way to go. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I updated the answer per your request there.